# Crystal Report Paging Issue

Tags: crystal-reports

Please i have a simple crystal report like below.
[image]

I just want it to display the three columns . However, incase of pagination, it does not close the end of the first page. It rather leaves it like below.

[image]

Also in some pages, it only prints like few records and leave the remaining page drawn to the end also unclosed. Please i am not sure how to fix this and is taking really long time. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have used lines in between columns that is causing the real problem here. Make sure that you limit the line to fit the section and not exceed forward.